# how to list the images stored by google compute engine using Node?

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine

I am trying to use NodeJS in order to list all the images available to a Google Compute Engine account.

I try to get the same result as this command line in JSON format using Node:

```
gcutil listimages --project=google
```

1. I started from this piece of code https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client
2. I look into this todo' sample too: https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_nodejs/

but now, I am stuck and I can't really link the samples with the documentation (see the link in the code as I can't paste more than 2 links if reputation is < to 10 :-)

Here is the code I am starting with. Could you tell me how to

```
/*
 Retrieves the list of image resources available to the specified project.

 command line: gcutil listimages --project=google
 REST API: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/images/list
 */

"use strict";

var googleapis = require('googleapis');
var authclient = new googleapis.OAuth2Client();
var compute = new googleapis.auth.Compute();

var projectName = process.argv[2] || 'google';

var gceService;

var usage = 'usage: listimages.js <project name>';

compute.authorize(function (err, result) {
    console.assert(!err, err);
    googleapis.discover('compute', 'v1beta15')
        .withAuthClient(compute)
        .execute(function (err, client) {
            console.assert(!err, err);

            //here I want to instantiate a Google Compute Engine service
            //this does not work (obviously)
            gceService = client.instanciateGoogleComputeEngineService();

            console.log('an instance of a GCE service is made !');
        });
});

// the following line isn't part of the code, I just try to help you understand my needs :-)
console.log(gceService.listimages(projectName);
```

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Google Compute Engine images are stored in Google Cloud Service, you really want to use the Compute Engine API. Take a look at the sample code at https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/api/javascript-guide

Specifically https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/compute/v1beta16/compute.images.list

When I send this `GET` command

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1beta16/projects/rti-latency/global/images?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I see the result

```
200 OK


{
 "kind": "compute#imageList",
 "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/compute/v1beta16/projects/<project-id>/global/images",
 "id": "projects/<project-id>/global/images",
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "compute#image",
   "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/compute/v1beta16/projects/<project-id>/global/images/rti-5-debian-7-20140110",
   "id": "17737537448393276537",
   "creationTimestamp": "2014-01-09T14:25:56.614-08:00",
   "name": "rti-5-debian-7-20140110",
   "description": "",
   "sourceType": "RAW",
   "rawDisk": {
    "containerType": "TAR",
    "source": ""
   },
   "status": "READY",
   "archiveSizeBytes": "2278217814"
  }
 ]
}
```

You need something like this

```
function listImages() {
       var request = gapi.client.compute.images.list({
         'project': DEFAULT_PROJECT,
         'zone': DEFAULT_ZONE
       });
       executeRequest(request, 'listImages');
     }

 function executeRequest(request, apiRequestName) {
       request.execute(function (resp) {
         newWindow = window.open(apiRequestName, '', 'width=600, height=600, scrollbars=yes');
         newWindow.document.write('<h1>' + apiRequestName + '</h1> <br />'
           + '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(resp.result, null, ' ') + '</pre>');
       });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

One you have the `compute` variable setup, you can use the following api to query the API:

```
compute.request(opts, function(err, result) {
   callback(err, result);
});
```

where `opts` should include the `uri`, `method` and the form `data`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [stephenplusplus/gce-images](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/gce-images) NPM module:

```
var gceImages = require("gce-images");
var images = gceImages({ keyFile: "..." });

images.getAll(function (err, images) {
    // images contains a JSON with all the available images
});
```

See [this](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/gce-images#gce-images) for more details.